# Bypass static member to decorated class

Tags: typescript, decorator

```
class SmthImpl {
    static readonly staticConst = 7;
}

function decorator(opts?: any) {
    return function (Class: { new() }) {
        return class Wrapper {
            // ...
        };
    }
}

const Smth = decorator()(SmthImpl);
```

Now I'd like to access `Smth.staticConst` but it's not there: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20SmthImpl%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20readonly%20staticConst%20%3D%207%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20decorator%28opts%3F%3A%20any%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20%28Class%3A%20%7B%20new%28%29%20%7D%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20class%20Wrapper%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20Smth%20%3D%20decorator%28%29%28SmthImpl%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log%28Smth.staticConst%29%3B)

> Property 'staticConst' does not exist on type 'typeof Wrapper'.

I've tried to add

```
Object.assign(Smth, SmthImpl);
```

but typescript emits the same error.

How can I write my code to get access to static members?

Answer (score 1):

You need change the `Class` parameter to be of a generic type `T` which extends a constructor. The difference is that `T` will be inferred to be the whole class (`typeof SmthImpl`) instead of just the constructor of `SmthImpl`. Also you need to use `Class` as the base type of `Wrapper` currently you don't use it for anything in the function body:

```
function decorator(opts?: any) {
    return function<T extends new (...args: any[]) => object> (Class: T) {
        return class Wrapper extends Class{

        };
    }
}

const Smth = decorator()(SmthImpl);
Smth.staticConst; // Works as expected.
```

Comment: Nice. But is it possible without inheritance from `Class`? Actually I'm doing react high order component and it should not extend the component provided to it as I understand.